# How do I use product.media.size to return an integer to use in product.media array

Tags: shopify

I was hoping I could use product.media.size to return an integer to be used in getting media by index.
Here is what I'm using now:

```
{% if product.media.size > 9 %}
  <div style = "padding-bottom: 15px">
      <div class="row">
        <figure style = "margin: 0px">
    <img class = "column" src="{{ product.media[8] | img_url: '500x500'}}">
        </figure>
            <figure style = "margin: 0px">
    <img class = "column" src="{{ product.media[9] | img_url: '500x500'}}"> 
            </figure>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
    <img src="{{ product.media[10] | img_url: '1000x1000'}}">
      </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

But I would like to do something like this if possible but its not working currently

```
{% if product.media.size > 9 %}
  <div style = "padding-bottom: 15px">
      <div class="row">
        <figure style = "margin: 0px">
    <img class = "column" src="{{ product.media[product.media.size-2] | img_url: '500x500'}}">
        </figure>
            <figure style = "margin: 0px">
    <img class = "column" src="{{ product.media[product.media.size-1] | img_url: '500x500'}}"> 
            </figure>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
    <img src="{{ product.media[product.media.size] | img_url: '1000x1000'}}">
      </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you check out [this tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-theme-support-for-rich-media-3d-and-video).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In liquid the `-` sign isn't used to subtract numbers, you have to use the `minus` filter, here are the [Liquid math filters](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/math-filters).

I'm not sure that this `{{ product.media[product.media.size | minus: 2] | img_url: '500x500'}}` would work though.

So I assigned the numbers you wanted to variables, this should work:

```
{% if product.media.size > 9 %}
  {% assign media_size = product.media.size %}
  {% assign media_size_minus_2 = media_size | minus: 2 %}
  {% assign media_size_minus_1 = media_size | minus: 1 %}
  
  <div style = "padding-bottom: 15px">
    <div class="row">
      <figure style = "margin: 0px">
        <img class = "column" src="{{ product.media[media_size_minus_2] | img_url: '500x500'}}">
      </figure>
      <figure style = "margin: 0px">
        <img class = "column" src="{{ product.media[media_size_minus_1] | img_url: '500x500'}}"> 
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="{{ product.media[media_size] | img_url: '1000x1000'}}">
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```